# How to create a panel with an organized "list" of information in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, layout-manager

I'm trying to create a panel that has information on it.

I've tried using the `setBorderLayout` to add the labels with the information to certain areas of the panel, but I know this doesn't work as it just overwrites what I already had before.

Here is an example from my code:

```
        final JFrame fr = new JFrame("ATCGUI");
        fr.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        JPanel tab1 = new JPanel();
        tab1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        tabbedPane.addTab("Airport", tab1);

        JLabel labelAirportName = new JLabel(airportInfo[0]);
        tab1.add(labelAirportName, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel labelAirportCodeStatic = new JLabel("Code:");
        JLabel labelAirportLocationStatic = new JLabel("Location:");
        JLabel labelAirportCoordinatesStatic = new JLabel("Coordinates:");
        JLabel labelAirportAltitudeStatic = new JLabel("Altitude:");
        JLabel labelAirportTimezoneStatic = new JLabel("Timezone:");
        JLabel labelAirportICAOStatic = new JLabel("ICAO:");
        tab1.add(labelAirportCodeStatic, BorderLayout.WEST);
        tab1.add(labelAirportLocationStatic, BorderLayout.WEST);
        tab1.add(labelAirportCoordinatesStatic, BorderLayout.WEST);
        tab1.add(labelAirportAltitudeStatic, BorderLayout.WEST);
        tab1.add(labelAirportTimezoneStatic, BorderLayout.WEST);
        tab1.add(labelAirportICAOStatic, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

This ends up creating something like this:

[image]

When I am aiming for something that looks more like this:

[image]

I created this with the SwingUI designer but due to compatibility I am switching over to just Swing

Comment: Check out the [Swing Tutorial on Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). A `GridLayout` might fit your needs. Usually, the desired result can be achieved by combining multiple layouts.

Comment: @maloomeister Thanks for the link! I didn't know about the different layout managers.

Comment: This is only a part of the Oracle Swing Tutorial. You can have a look at the complete [Swing Tutorial Overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). It is a great place to start, as it provides many working examples.

Comment: @maloomeister Yeah, I've been having a look through it, I guess I just never got to that part.

Answer (score 1):

Following the Oracle Swing tutorial linked by maloomeister https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

I was able to create the layout I wanted by mixing BorderLayout and GridLayout.